# How can I make Firefox remember my session while still clearing the browsing history on close?

Tags: firefox, browser, restore, history, session

I am aware, thanks to a thread <sup>[1]</sup>, that Firefox doesn't save sessions when browsing history is cleared at close, as effectively the open tabs are themselves cleared from the history before the session is saved.

But I would like Firefox to behave differently. Is there any way to change Firefox's behavior so it will clear my browsing history when it closes, but remember only that a certain list of tabs were open, and then restore those tabs when it opens (not even necessarily with those tabs' histories)?

I'm running Firefox 3.5.6 on Mac OS X 10.5.

<sub>[1] https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/381229</sub>

Comment: The link is broken now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) addon, having its own session manager would be able to do this. You'll need to tweak the built in Firefox settings via Tools-Options-"Firefox will never remember history". I'm *fairly* sure that it'll work on Mac.

Comment: I do use TMP and used to use it on Windows before FF had its own session manager, but found the TMP session restore to cause my machine to perform poorly, a view I've seen echoed in other comments recently--but granted I haven't tried it myself with the latest FF and on this system. Do you have any experience with TMP's session manager--do you know whether it's stable and whether it slows the machine down much?

Comment: For me (with Windows &, FF 3.5) the TMP extension is perfectly stable and without noticeable performance hit, but I use FF's session manager. TMP is such an automatic addon I haven't tried without for a long time so can't say what my system would be like without. I do know that it is incompatible with many other tab manager/tweak extensions. You can always try it, and report back if you don't like it.

Comment: TMP didn't even work at restoring the session for me, so I didn't even get to the phase of comparing performance. I may be doing something wrong; I do have a lot of extensions that may compete with each other.

Comment: Via the TMP dialogue, in the "session" tab, make sure to uncheck "Use Firefox's built in session restore". You then get a bunch of options. Any good?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Actually that is precisely what I did that did not work. I will try again the next time FF has a significant update....

Comment: I'm just using Chrome now so I figure this is the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need for a add-on...

You can manually force the "session restore" page to appear any time by simply using:

about:sessionrestore

It was found at http://www.webupd8.org/2009/08/quick-firefox-35-tip-manually-open.html

Well, there is way to get back the Session Restore page manually, by typing this in the URL bar:

```
about:sessionrestore
```

So the next time when you accidentally click on the wrong button, use the above trick to get back the session restore page.

See also

- firefox_2_and_making_session_restore_useful.html
- how-to-fix-annoying-youtube-jumpiness-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how much control you need, in addition to the aforementioned options, *Tab Mix Plus* also has a *Lock Tab* and a *Protect Tab* option, which may prove to be what you need.

If you wish to take that a stage further you could take a look at [PermaTabs Mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7816) which provides similar functionality.

Further still would be [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/2324). This replaces the inbuilt session manager and that of Tab Mix plus, and offers additional functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but I found a sophisticated solution. In preferences go to Privacy & Security -> History. Choose "Use a personalized configuration for the history" and uncheck all the fields below, that's it!
Explanation: If the field "Delete history after closing Firefox" is unchecked, the tabs will be kept. But if the two fields to keep the history (Visited pages and downloads / formulaires) are unchecked, no history will be saved at all. That's why if all the fields remain unchecked it will work as required!